# How to remount filesystem at logout?

Tags: logout, disk-cleanup

I need to clear tmpfs after each logout from system (Ubuntu x86_64).

Comment: what do you mean? so any user will clear it at logon? what is the purpose? more details will help you get a better answer.

Comment: The user will repeatedly logout . I need get the mountpoint in tmpfs without data at each logout (without reboot).

Comment: so you just want the mount point of tmpfs? `grep '^tmpfs' /proc/mounts`

Comment: no, i want to erase all data after logout (easier to just remount).

Comment: vinegret, a `umount`/`mount` ("remount") will not clear the file system, it will just "disconnect"/"reconnect" it from/to the file system hierarchy.

Comment: Janis, rtfm tmpfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [pam-tmpdir](https://sources.debian.net/src/pam-tmpdir/) and [pam-mount](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/).

pam-mount mounts and unmounts directories when PAM sessions are started and finished (which includes when users log in and out).

pam-tmpdir creates a user-specific temporary directory each time someone logs in, which may come in handy if you're trying to isolate users from each other.

Note that in any case there may be daemons which have files in `/tmp` that they expect to keep around longer than a user's session; so I'd recommend going with a user-specific temporary directory, using either pam-mount or pam-tmpdir.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need. But i don't found a this packages for x64 architecture (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: In Debian and Ubuntu, the packages are respectively `libpam-tmpdir` and `libpam-mount`.