# Per user tmpfs directories

Tags: security, fhs, tmpfs

Using the shared `/tmp` directory is known to have lead to many security vulnerabilities when predictable filenames have been used. And randomly generated names aren't really nice looking.

I am thinking that maybe it would be better to use a per user temporary directory instead. Many applications will use the `TMPDIR` environment variable in order to decide where temporary files goes.

On login I could simply set `TMPDIR=/temp/$USER` where `/temp` would then have to contain a directory for each user with that directory being writable to that user and nobody else.

But in that case I would still like `/temp` to be a `tmpfs` mountpoint, which means that the subdirectories would not exist after a reboot and need to be recreated somehow.

Is there any (de-facto) standard for how to create a `tmpfs` with per user subdirectories? Or would I have to come up with my own non-standard tools to dynamically generate such directories?

Comment: I now found that Ubuntu has `/run/user` which looks almost like what I was looking for (except that `/run` by default can only use 1/5 the space that other tmpfs are allowed to).

Comment: If you want more room in `/run/user` then probably `mount -o remount,size=larger% /run/user/uid` should work, though, if on ubuntu, you'll probably want to escalate with `sudo` for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pam-tmpdir](https://sources.debian.net/src/pam-tmpdir/) for this. It creates a directory for each user that logs in, at the start of their PAM session.

See [How to remount filesystem at logout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192142/how-to-remount-filesystem-at-logout/192250) for a little more context...

In Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives it's available in `libpam-tmpdir`.

Comment: Defaulting to `/tmp/user` for the location does not fully meet my requirements. so at the very least I'd have to reconfigure it to use a different path. I suppose that means there isn't another standard location for this kind of thing, and I'd have to make up my own idea about what path to use.

Comment: It's actually `/tmp/user/$UID`, so each user gets their own directory.

Comment: Sure, but it is still possible for somebody to grab the name `/tmp/user` before root.

Comment: If you want to avoid that, you can configure `libpam-tmpdir` to fail by specifying "required" instead of "optional", which prevents login in an unsafe context. `root` gets `/tmp/user/0`, not `/tmp/user`.

Comment: I'd still rather have it use a location, where that possibility doesn't even exist. That would be the case if I used `/run` rather than `/tmp`. It turns out that `/run/user` already exists and is created in a way quite similar to what I am looking for.

Comment: Right, set that up in `/etc/security/tmpdir.conf` and you're good to go...

Comment: @kasperd In fact some distributions do set up `TMPDIR=/run/$USER/tmp` or some such by default nowadays.

Comment: @Gilles If you included a reference to some documentation with that, then that would be a full answer and not just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in `/etc/fstab`. A line for a particular user might look like:

```
tmpfs /home/username/tmp tmpfs size=[num]%,uid=[num],gid=[num],noauto,user,mode=0700
```

Putting a line like that for each user you want to be able to mount a tmpfs in their home directory will make it so. The user *username* could do just do `mount ~/tmp` to mount a tmpfs over their home directory `~/tmp` at a 10% current system memory capacity. The mode is set to `0700` so only that user *(and root of course)* can do anything with the contents of that mount. And the mount is not made automatically - the user has to request it.

You'll want to replace all of that for the relevant values. For example, for yourself you might do:

```
tmpfs /home/kasperd/tmp tmpfs size=25%,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,user,mode=0700 0 1
```

...if your user and group id are both 1000.

Comment: I could imagine that mounting it on a sub directory of home directory could lead to security issues if the user replace the mount point with a symlink. It also doesn't scale well with multiple users. And getting it to work together with ecryptfs could be tricky.

Comment: @kasperd - Suit yourself - I don't understand where you're going with any of that. All of the things you mention should just work - you can have mountpoints of different kinds in the same tree - mounting a tmpfs to an ecryptfs shouldn't be any issue at all. Replacing a mount-point w/ a symlink won't give anyone else access to the mountpoint if its mode is 0700. And it will scale just as well as you can script it - it's a simple script, though, just comparing lines in `fstab` to registered ~. You can get more elaborate of course, but I don't see the need.